# Kohana Database query builder with JOIN & ON & AND

Tags: join, kohana, kohana-3.2

I'm working on a query that uses COALESCE for retrieving localized strings for my current project

The sql works when used as a raw query but i cant seem to get the joins structured in this way with the query builder

```
LEFT JOIN text as text_se
ON (main_table.text = text_se.id)
AND (text_se.lang_code = 'SV')
```

This code:

```
->join(array('text', 'text_se', 'LEFT')
    ->on('main_table.text', '=', 'text_se.id')
    ->on('text_se.lang_code', '=', 'SV')
```

Only results in

```
LEFT JOIN text as text_se
ON (main_table.text = text_se.id AND text_se.lang_code = 'SV')
```

Which doesn't do the same...
Have anyone else used AND after the JOIN-statement and can help me with it?

Comment: Can you post the full raw query?

Answer (score 6):

Or you could do this....

```
->join(array('text', 'text_se'), 'LEFT')
    ->on('main_table.text', '=', DB::Expr('text_se.id AND text_se.lang_code = "SV"'))
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work in 3.1.x:

```
->join(array('text', 'text_se', 'LEFT')
->on('main_table.text', '=', DB::expr('text_se.id'))
->on('text_se.lang_code', '=', DB::expr('SV'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use where:

```
->join(array('text', 'text_se', 'LEFT')
->on('main_table.text', '=', 'text_se.id')
->where('text_se.lang_code', '=', 'SV')
```

Comment: This may work in this instance, but the where parameter will affect only the where clause. In some instances it's desirable to join tables on multiple conditions to further optimize queries.

Comment: in this case LEFT JOIN will act like INNER JOIN